# Grunt task that can copy 'default files' to a destination directory?

Tags: gruntjs

Does anyone know how I can create a custom Grunt task that is able to copy files saved within the published grunt task?

For example the task:

```
node_modules/grunt-foo/tasks/foo.js
node_modules/grunt-foo/tasks/support/foo-boilerplate.txt
```

The task in my Gruntfile

```
foo: {
     dest: "target/foo"
}
```

When the task runs I would want "foo-boilerplate.txt" to "target/foo/".

```
target/foo/foo-boilerplate.txt
```

There'll be more going on in the task so I don't want to imply that all I'm doing is copying boilerplate code over.  It is just one use case within the task.

Can someone give me an example of how I can do this within my foo.js task file?

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to copy some files to some destination, right?

Start by defining that copy operation using grunt-contrib-copy:

```
copy: {
  boilercode: {
    src: ['node_modules/grunt-foo/tasks/support/foo-boilerplate.txt'],
    dest: 'target/foo',
  },
},
```

Then you want your foo task to perform a number of other tasks, including that copy operation:

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', ['copy:boilercode', 'anothersupertask', 'yetanothertask']);
```

... all you now have to do is have something done in anothersupertask.

```
grunt. registerMultiTask('anothersupertask', 'super!', function(){})
```

Am I missing something? (I don't know what you call "the published grunt task")

For reference:

- [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)
- [grunt tasks](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks)

Comment: I wasn't looking to have a copy task within my Gruntfile.  I have a simple case here.  The filters for the files I'd be copying over is much larger and not reasonable to have copied from project to project.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  Within my multi-task I used __dirname to reference the directory that were the task was located.

```
var fileToCopy = path.join(__dirname, "support", "foo-boilerplate.txt");
file.copy(fileToCopy, path.join(target, "foo-boilerplate.txt"));
```